# Show the two events closest to today in the future (ACF)

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I want to display the two dates that are closest to the current date, but only if they're in the future. I'm using the [ACF date-picker](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/date-picker/) for this.

I'm not very good at php, so I'd appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try something like:

```
$args = array(
   'post_type' => 'your_post_type',
   'posts_per_page' => 2,
   'meta_query' => array(
        'key'           => 'your_field_key',
        'compare'       => '>',
        'value'         => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
        'type'          => 'DATETIME'
   )
);
```

Hope that helps?

Comment: Thanks! I should've mentioned that I'm not using custom post types and that the fields I need to get are out of a repeater!

Comment: Hi, so you just set the post type to post and the key to the field key.